# Read the ecosystem variables with Mocha (units tests)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am writing units tests in NodeJS with Mocha.
I use pm2 to start and deploy my application.

However, when i try to get the environment variables with Mocha, it says `undefined`.

I try to set the variable in the command line like that `SET NODE_SRV=myserv` but i need to have multiple variables.

I have a ecosystem.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
apps : [

//My APP
{
  name      : 'My APP,
  script    : './serveur.js',
  instances : 1,
  exec_mode : "cluster",
  env_dev : {
    NODE_ENV: 'dev',
    NODE_PORT_FRONT: '4000',
    NODE_PROT_FRONT: 'http:',
    NODE_PORT_BACK: '4001',
    NODE_PROT_BACK: 'http:',
    NODE_SRV: 'myserv'
  }
}]
```

};

with my variables but I can't read them even if i start my application before doing my test.

To run mocha I simply do `mocha --exit`.

If anyone have an idea on how to read the variables from the ecosystem in Mocha, I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

```
set NODE_ENV=dev && mocha --require ./ecosystem.config.js --exit
```

Comment: Hello, it works but with that i can set one variable and i want to use variables i put in my ecosystem.config.js

Comment: ecosystem.config.js i think a separate file,i have updated the answer

Comment: the option `--config` is  unknown.

Comment: can you try with  --require..i have updated the answer